# Serialize available choices and mark selected

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am new to REST and django-rest-framework. I want to get list of available ManyToMany choices along with some way to know which ones are currently selected.

I have model like this:

```
class PGroup(models.Model):
    .
    permissions = models.ManyToManyField(
        Permission, related_name="group_permissions", help_text=_('Select permissions for this group.')
    )
```

Serializers.

```
class PermissionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Permission
        fields = ['pk', 'name',]



class PGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    permissions = PermissionSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = PGroup
        fields = [....'permissions']
```

Looking at Browseable API, with this setup I get 'permissions: []'(empty list) for `generics.createAPIView` and get the associated 'permissions[....]'(non-empty list) for `generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView`.

I want a list of available `permissions` on both API views and also want to know which permissions are already selected for Update API view.

Can anyone please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to get the list of choices.

Using the [`SerializerMethodField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield),

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Permission

class PGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    permissions = PermissionSerializer(many=True)
    all_available_permissions = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    
    def get_all_available_permissions(self, obj):
        return Permission.objects.all()

    class Meta:
        model = PGroup
        fields = ['permissions', "all_available_permissions"]
```

or using [`source`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#using-source), we can define a custom method on the model and point the serializer to use it using the `source` argument.

```py
### models.py

class PGroup(models.Model):
    .
    permissions = models.ManyToManyField(
        Permission, related_name="group_permissions", help_text=_('Select permissions for this group.')
    )
    
    def all_permissions(self):
        return Permission.objects.all()
        
        
### serializers.py

class PGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    permissions = PermissionSerializer(many=True)
    all_available_permissions = PermissionSerializer(many=True, read_only=True, source="all_permissions")

    class Meta:
        model = PGroup
        fields = ['permissions', "all_available_permissions"]
```

2nd option is much better, IMO.

> Note: you may not always want to send a full list of choices as that could get really slow overtime when u have hundreds or thousands of objects.